# Filter hours in datetime using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to filter objects with a datetime field in the following way.

I have a lower and upper limit for hours and a separate lower and upper limit for dates. For example, I want to get all the objects  between May 1, 2013 and April 12, 2014 with an hour anywhere between 7 and 17.

I know approximately how I would do this in Django, but I can't find any resources explaining how to do it with SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Can you please specify the RDBMS you use?

Comment: Using SQLite for the moment, with the intention to use Postgres in production.